# SVN checkout projects trunk and branches without tags

Tags: svn, copy, large-data, svn-checkout

I have a large project in SVN with classical structure:

```
myproject/
  branches/
    developer1-mybranch1/
    developer2-mybranch3/
    ...
  tags/
    tag1/
    tag2/
    ....
  trunk/
```

I want to create a new branch from trunk and as I know, I should checkout repository to my computer. Can I checkout only trunk and branches folders? What I must do for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to checkout the whole repository to create a branch, just

```
svn cp $TRUNKURL $NEWBRANCHURL
```

Comment: Thanks! It is more transparent in git and I have confused when first tyime use svn :)